# C++ entry point -> main()

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, portable-executable

I am writing my own little user mode debugger for fun. I know that the entry point specified in the PE header is not the programs defined main() (as far as microsoft c++ runtime is concerned anyway)

Where can I find some documentation on the calls that take place between this entry point, up until the actual main() function, and why they are called, and what they do?

Comment: Highly implementation specific. What platform? Compiler?

Comment: Visual studio 2010, Pe32+ format windows 7 x64

Comment: It is runtime internals so you have following options: debug/disassemble or search over hackers (in good sense) resources.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I tagged it so it might be more likely to get an answer.

Comment: [Here](http://vxheavens.com/lib/viz00.html) is a good article on what GCC does on start-up. Also check out the crt source code that's shipped with MSVC, `crt0.c` in particular.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. In fact main may not exist. E.g: you can override the default CRT entry point used by the linker, the main can be inlined into the CRT startup function, etc...

Comment: I guess his question really is what happens between entry point and startup function, it is not really about `main`.

Answer (score 1):

The source code for the CRT comes with Visual Studio. For example, for Visual Studio 2010 default installation location, it's at:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src
```

The actual `main()` is in `crt0.c`.

The different types of CRT (static, DLL, MT, x86, x64, etc.) are controlled by some defines like `CRTDLL`, `_M_IA64` and more. You'll see when you dig in.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the calls etc., the action of the code, is not documented except by the source code itself.

Place cursor first in `main` and use debugger "run to here". Or set a breakpoint there. Then just inspect the calls in the call stack.

Cheers & hth.,